# how to solve a histogram which just has the value x and no vertical or horizontal values

Tags: probability-distributions

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oWQB3.png)

The following histogram only has the values of X without a horizontal and vertical axis. Please look at the image and help me answer the questions.

Comment: Welcome to MSE.  You'll get a lot more help, and fewer votes to close, if you show that you have made a real effort to solve the problem yourself.  What are your thoughts?  What have you tried?  How far did you get?  Where are you stuck?  This question is likely to be closed if you don't add more context.  Please respond by **editing the question body.**  Many people browsing questions will vote to close without reading the comments.